# Failed to convert a NumPy array ((the whole sequence is a string)) to a Tensor, in genome sequence classification for CNN?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

The data is basically in CSV format, which is a fasta/genome sequence, basically the whole sequence is a string. To pass this data into a CNN model I convert the data into numeric. The genome/fasta sequence, which I want to change into tensor acceptable format so I convert this string into float e.g., "AACTG,...,AAC.." to [[0.25,0.25,0.50,1.00,0.75],....,[0.25,0.25,0.50.....]]. But the conversion data shows like this (see #data show 2). But, when I run **tf.convert_to_tensor(train_data)** it gives me an error of Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray). But in order to pass the data into CNN model, it has to be a tensor, but I don't know why it gives an error! What will be the solution to it?

```
# data show 2
array([array([0.25, 0.5 , 0.5 , ..., 0.75, 0.25, 0.25]),
array([0.25, 0.75, 0.25, ..., 1.  , 0.5 , 0.5 ]), ...,
array([0.25, 1.  , 1.  , ..., 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])], dtype=object)
# end of data show
```

[DataFrame of my genome/fasta sequence look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POlQ0.png)

Underneath is the function used for encoding the data.

```
def string_to_array(my_string):
    my_string = my_string.lower()
    my_string = re.sub('[^acgt]', 'z', my_string)
    my_array = list(my_string)
    return my_array

# create a label encoder with 'acgtz' alphabet
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(['a','c','g','t','z'])

def ordinal_encoder(my_array):
    integer_encoded = label_encoder.transform(my_array)
    float_encoded = integer_encoded.astype(float)
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 0] = 0.25 # A
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 1] = 0.50 # C
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 2] = 0.75 # G
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 3] = 1.00 # T
    float_encoded[float_encoded == 4] = 0.00 # anything else, z
    return float_encoded
def conversion(tdf):
    data = []
    for i in tdf.index:
        val = tdf['seq'].iloc[i]
        val = ordinal_encoder(string_to_array(val))
        data.append(val)
    return data

train_data = conversion(df) # calling the function
train_data = np.asarray(train_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in your numpy array dtype.

Using array with dtype `float32` should fix problem: `tf.convert_to_tensor(train_data.astype(np.float32))`

Comment: the following code which you give gives me a ValueError. 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. @kacpo1

Comment: So that means one of two things. First, your array isn't propper numpy multi-dimensional array or second you have objects that are not floats in this array.

Comment: yes, you are right I also think the same way but as you see in (#data show 2) when I call the train_data variable to display the output (before calling the tf.convert_to_tensor), it is in multiple dimensions, but it also says that this is an object data type. But I don't get why it gives me object data type? @kacpo1

Comment: Are all elements of this array equal lenght? This can cause both problems (dtype object and ValueError)

Comment: No, all elements are in different lengths like 29000 or 28707, and some are the same...., but the LabelEncoder successfully change all the string elements into float. Do you suggest making all the elements length same will solve the problem? Can you please explain me? @kacpo1

Comment: It will solve the problem, but it will also change your data. If you want `tf.data.Dataset` object, you can use `tf.data.Dataset.from_iterator()` to create dataset directly from list.

Comment: I didn't get it! Still, I need to convert the string dataset to float type data, and I couldn't find any documentation regarding `tf.data.Dataset.from_iterator()` [tf.data documentation] (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset). Can you give me a link? and also which data should I use for `tf.data.Dataset` is it converted data or directly from the pandas DataFrame? @kacpo1

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`. You can use already generated data or make it in generator function.